Does the formation of a neutron star always require a supernova explosion?
Is a supernova explosion an essential condition for the formation of a neutron stars?

Perhaps the merger of two white dwarves could do it? Or a white dwarf pulling matter from a binary companion?

It seems likely that there will always be a big explosion, but whether there is always an ultra-luminous electromagnetic signal is an interesting, unresolved question.
The difference in size between a neutron star ($\sim 10$ km) and the next known stable configuration of electron-degenerate matter ($\sim 1000$ km) means that get from the latter to the former involves getting rid of
$$\Delta E \sim 2\times 10^{46}\left(\frac{M}{M_\odot}\right)^2\ {\rm J}$$
of gravitational potential energy. Since there are no intermediate stable states and since weakly-interacting, and hence freely-escaping, neutrinos are inevitably involved in creating neutron-rich matter, the collapse to a neutron star would usually be violently quick (under a second). i.e. An explosion.
However, your question specifically asks about supernovae and you might be thinking about the characteristic electromagnetic signature, rather than the inevitable neutrino pulse.
One possibility that is often discussed are failed supernovae, where the core of a massive star collapsed, but fails to blow off its outer envelope. Although these might initially produce proto neutron stars (a) there is still some sort of explosive event hidden inside the star, (b) the envelope will be accreted forming a black hole rather than a neutron star.
The best bet for a muted electromagnetic explosion is the "accretion-induced collapse" (AIC) of a white dwarf. Normally, such events would lead to a type Ia supernova and the total thermonuclear destruction of the white dwarf. But rarely, if the progenitor is a massive white dwarf made of oxygen, neon and magnesium (less massive white dwarfs would typically have a carbon/oxygen composition), thermonuclear runaway may be avoided, electron-capture forms neutrons and the collapse produces a neutron star (Fryer et al. 1999).
Recent hydrodynamic simulations of the process (Longo Micchi et al. 2023; Yip et al. 2024) suggest that a slowly accreting massive white dwarf can collapse, ejecting only $<0.01 M_\odot$, with very little radioactive nickel produced. Although copious neutrinos are emitted, as usual, during the collapse, such an "explosion" may, electromagnetically, be 2 orders of magnitude fainter than a normal type Ia supernova and shorter-lived (only a few days). No events of this kind have yet been observed.

Isn't this conversion a type 1a supernova?  Which would make there be no path other than a supernova.

@LorenPechtel it may be possible to have a "failed" type Ia that produces a neutron star by accretion induced collapse and I have revised my answer.
